# CALayer animation to move from one point to another

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-animation, calayer, mask

I am trying to animate a sublayer on a root layer which is attached to a UIView in objective C ios. I have tried number of answers available here but the sublayer is fixed and not changing its position at all.

I have tried the following method to animate it :

```
    -(void)moveLayer:(CALayer*)layer to:(CGPoint)point with:(CGRect)bounds
    {
        CGMutablePathRef thePath = CGPathCreateMutable();
        CGPathMoveToPoint(thePath,NULL,74.0,74.0);
        
        
        CAKeyframeAnimation * theAnimation;
        
        // Create the animation object, specifying the position property as the key path.
        theAnimation=[CAKeyframeAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"position"];
        theAnimation.path=thePath;
        theAnimation.duration=5.0;
        
        // Add the animation to the layer.
        [layer addAnimation:theAnimation forKey:@"position"];
    
    }
```

And also using

```
`
                    [featureLayer setFrame:oldRect];
                    
                    CGRect oldBounds = oldRect;
                    CGRect newBounds = faceRect;
                    
                    CABasicAnimation* revealAnimation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"bounds"];
                    revealAnimation.fromValue = [NSValue valueWithCGRect:oldBounds];
                    revealAnimation.toValue = [NSValue valueWithCGRect:newBounds];
                    revealAnimation.duration = 3.0;
                    
                    // Update the bounds so the layer doesn't snap back when the animation completes.
                    featureLayer.bounds = newBounds;
                    
                    [featureLayer addAnimation:revealAnimation forKey:@"revealAnimation"];
                    
                    
                    [self.previewLayer setMask:featureLayer];
`
```

If any one can help me out it will be great. Thanks in advance.

## Edit 1

Just to be sure this is a mask image over the root layer, i want to animate the mask to move from one position to other but it is staying still.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try below code.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    CAShapeLayer *shape = [CAShapeLayer new];
    shape.path = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithOvalInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, 50, 50)].CGPath;
    shape.fillColor = [UIColor redColor].CGColor;
    shape.position = CGPointMake(self.view.bounds.size.width / 2 - 25, 100);
    [self.view.layer addSublayer:shape];

    [self performSelector:@selector(doAnimation:) withObject:shape afterDelay:1];
    //[self performSelector:@selector(doKeyFrameAnimation:) withObject:shape afterDelay:1];
}

- (void)doAnimation:(CALayer*)layer {
    NSLog(@"%@",layer);

    CABasicAnimation *anim = [CABasicAnimation new];
    anim.duration = 2;
    anim.keyPath = @"position.y";
    anim.fromValue = @(layer.position.y);
    anim.toValue = @300;

    [layer addAnimation:anim forKey:@"move_down"]; 
}

// the KeyFrameAnimation way
- (void)doKeyFrameAnimation:(CALayer*)layer {

    UIBezierPath *path = [UIBezierPath new];
    [path moveToPoint:layer.position];
    [path addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(layer.position.x, 300)];

    CAKeyframeAnimation *anim = [CAKeyframeAnimation new];
    anim.duration = 2;
    anim.keyPath = @"position";
    anim.path = path.CGPath;

    [layer addAnimation:anim forKey:@"move_down_by_keyframe"];
}
```